# How to implement a Cloneable template class in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a Cloneable base class. Here's the code:

```
class Base1 {
public:
    virtual Base1* Clone() const {
        return new Base1(*this);
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base1 {
public:
    virtual Derived1* Clone() const {
        return new Derived1(*this);
    }
};


template<typename T>
class Cloneable {
public:
    virtual T* Clone() const {
        return new T(dynamic_cast<const T&>(*this));
    }
};

class Base2 : public Cloneable<Base2> {
};

class Derived2 : public Base2, public Cloneable<Derived2> {
};

namespace Lib_UnitTest {
TEST_CLASS(CloneableTest) {
public:
    // Success test
    TEST_METHOD(ShouldClone1) {
        Derived1 derived;
        Base1& base = derived;
        Base1* basePtr = base.Clone();
        Derived1* derivedPtr = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(basePtr);
        Assert::IsNotNull(derivedPtr);
    }

    // Failed test !!!
    TEST_METHOD(ShouldClone2) {
        Derived2 derived;
        Base2& base = derived;
        Base2* basePtr = base.Clone();
        Derived2* derivedPtr = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(basePtr);
        Assert::IsNotNull(derivedPtr);
    }
};
}
```

The problem here is the test case 'ShouldClone1' success, but 'ShouldClone2' failed.

It seems that in the 2nd test case, the Clone method doesn't go to the one of Derived class.

Do you know what's the problem? What's the difference between those 2 implementations?

---

I guess this is because of 'diamond' inheritance problem. But if use 'public virtual' inheritance and implement the Clone method in class Derived2, then I don't need to inherit Cloneable for it at the first place ...

A updated version:

```
class Cloneable {
public:
    // Could make this pure virtual
    virtual ~Cloneable() {}

    // Could make this pure virtual
    virtual Cloneable* Clone() const {
        return new Cloneable(*this);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class CloneableBase : public virtual Cloneable {
public:
    virtual ~CloneableBase() {}

    virtual Cloneable* Clone() const {
        return new T(dynamic_cast<const T&>(*this));
    }
};

class Base2 : public virtual CloneableBase<Base2> {
};

class Derived2 : public virtual Base2 {
    virtual Cloneable* Clone() const {
        return new Derived2(*this);
    }
};
```

---

Update 2：

The article [Polymorphic cloning and the CRTP](https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/) describes the solution quite clear.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the Clone() method in Derived2 should be a specialization of the Clone() method from Base2, as they are inherited from different classes (Cloneable<Derived2> versus Cloneable<Base2>).

Comment: @Ðаn I had a version using std::shared_ptr, but that didn't work since the Clone could not be overwritten, not sure about unique_ptr.

Comment: you can use `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @AndyT : That won't work.  The fact that `dynamic_cast` is returning NULL is telling you that he has called `Cloneable<Base2>::Clone` which has returned an object which is just a raw `Base2`.  If you use the `static_cast` you will be lying to the compiler, and it will get its revenge.

Comment: @MartinBonner: sorry, I meant in `Clonable<T>::Clone()`. In tests `dynamic_cast` is useful to spot this particular problem

Comment: @andy Ah right.  I don't think that will help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without manually writing Clone() method in every derived class. But we can not get away with just CRTP. Instead of instantiating Derived classes directly we will always indirectly instantiate super derived template class which will deal with diamond problem for us.

```
class IClonable
{
    public: virtual IClonable *
    CloneImpl(void) const = 0;

    public: virtual
    ~IClonable(void) {}
};

template< typename TClonable > TClonable *
Construct();

template< typename TBase >
class TheFinalClass final: public TBase, public virtual IClonable
{
    template< typename TClonable > friend TClonable *
    Construct();

    private:
    TheFinalClass(void) {}

    private: explicit
    TheFinalClass(TheFinalClass const & other): TBase(other) {}

    private: IClonable *
    CloneImpl(void) const override
    {
        return(new TheFinalClass(*this));
    }
};

template< typename TClonable > TClonable *
Construct() {return(new TheFinalClass< TClonable >());}

template< typename TDerived >
class Cloneable: public virtual IClonable
{
    public: TDerived *
    Clone() const // notice that this method does not override anything
    {
        return(dynamic_cast< TDerived * >(dynamic_cast< IClonable const * >(this)->CloneImpl()));
    }
};

class Base2: public Cloneable< Base2 > {};

class Derived2: public Cloneable< Derived2 >, public Base2 {};

// Failed test !!!, Now works!!!
TEST_METHOD(ShouldClone2) {
    Derived2 * p_derived{Construct< Derived2 >()};
    Base2 * p_base{p_derived};
    Base2 * p_clone_base{p_base->Clone()};
    Derived2 * p_clone_derived{dynamic_cast< Derived2 * >(p_clone_base)};
    Assert::IsNotNull(p_clone_derived);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to pass 'Construct< Derived2 >()' for every instance of Derived2? If that's the case, it is more complicated.

Comment: Derived2 is actually an abstract type that can not be instantiated directly. Since we already had a factory-like Clone() method replacing a copy constructor it makes sense to have a factory-like method Construct() to replace a normal constructor.